# How to do json.dumps to a list of dictionaries contains base64 encoded image

Tags: python, json, base64

I want to pass a list of dictionaries containing base64 images to Javascript in Django.

In HTML:

```
var img_list = {{list_images}}


<script>
    // Not sure if it is right way to retrieve the list.
    (function () {
        window.image_list = JSON.parse('{{list_images}}');
    }());
</script>
```

Views.py

```
image_list = [{'image_name': 'Hello',
               'image':b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBD',
               ... }]
args['list_images'] = json.dumps(image_list)
```

I got error at json.dumps().

```
Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

What is the right way to pass such list to Javascript?

Comment: try decoding your bytes to a string, maybe `data.decode('ascii')`?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The image is base64 encoded with base64.b64encode() and it's bytes. Image is retrieved from sqlite which was saved as BLOB (it's byte I believe). So, I need to convert the BLOB into string? Also, I like to know how to retrieve it from Javascript.

Comment: No, do that to the base64 encoded data. JSON does not distinguish between bytes and string, the most appropriate representation would be json str, so use that. From javascript? well, deserialize your json in javascript, no? isn't that the whole purpose?

Comment: so something to the effect of: `for data in img_list: data['image'] = data['image'].decode()`

Comment: BLOB ->base64.b64encode()->decode(). json.dumps() passed. Also, I got object in Javascript:  window.img_list = {{list_images|safe}}. No need to do JSON.parse(). Thanks.